# How do i write a regex pattern for a string ending with 3 numbers or a hypen?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that can either end with a hiphen or a 3 digit number (or a completely random text.)

I will need to evaluate a condition if it ends with a hiphen or a 3 digit number.(if its not a number or a hyphen,i am good)

I tried to use

```
   myString.matches("^.*\\d")
```

I can try to tweek this,with some help

but i really dont know how i can specify 3 digits along with "-". 
I can probably use `myString.endsWith("-")` for the latter,but if i can do it with regex,it'd be great too.

Some samples:

- **This is a string123**  Must return 123
- **This is another string randomtext or number -** must return -(Notice the hyphen)
- **This is another one 456** must return 456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

^.*(\d{3}|-)$

The $ means "finished/ends with"